# Laravel - big collection and page load slow

Tags: php, laravel, collections, relationship, eloquent-relationship

I have a project for food ordering. On my object(restaurant) show page I'm calling all product categories with relationship for `foreach` products that belongs to that category.

I'm also using laravel livewire and this is my `Component`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Stores;

use Livewire\Component;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Store;
use App\Models\CategoryProduct;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Http\Livewire\Cart;

use App\Models\Favourite;

use Session;
use Auth;

class Show extends Component
{
    public $store;
    public $categories;
    public $ratings;

    public $message = '';
    public $supplements = [];
    public $supplementsArray = [];

    public $features = [];
    public $featuresArray = '';

    public $quantity = 1;

    public $deliveryPrice = 0;

    public function render(Request $request)
    {
        if(!Session::has('cart')){
            return view('livewire.stores.show');
        }

        $items = explode('|', $this->featuresArray);

        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');

        $store_id = $this->store->id;

        $oldCart->deliveryPrice = $this->store->delivery_price;

        if($oldCart->storeId != $store_id){
            $request->session()->forget('cart');
        }

        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

        //dd(session()->get('cart'));

        return view('livewire.stores.show',[
            'products' => $cart->items,
            'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice + $cart->deliveryPrice,
            'totalQty' => $cart->totalQty,
            'ordersPrice' => $cart->ordersPrice,
            'storeId' => $cart->storeId,
        ]);
    } 
}
```

This `public $categories;` variable is from my Controller:

```
     /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $store = Store::find($id);
        $categories = CategoryProduct::where('store_id', $store->id)->get();

        $ratings = $store->getAllRatings($store->id);

        if($store->checkWorktime() == 'Zatvoreno'){
            return view('website.stores.closed', compact('store', 'categories', 'ratings'));
        }

        return view('website.stores.show', compact('store', 'categories', 'ratings'));
    }
```

And in my `blade` view this is how I'm viewing it:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
   <div class="row m-0" id="{{$category->id}}">
      <h6 class="p-3 m-0 bg-light font-weight-bold w-100">{{$category->title}} <span class="float-right"> 
         <small class="text-black-50">{{count($category->categoryProducts)}} proizvoda</small></span> 
      </h6>
      <div class="col-md-12 px-0 border-top">
         <div class="">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
               @foreach($category->categoryProducts as $product)                               
                  <a href="#0" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal{{$product->id}}">
                      <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-9">
                            <b class="text-dark">{{$product->title}}</b><br>
                            <small class="text-muted">{{$product->description}}</small><br><br>
                            @if($product->features->isNotEmpty())
                            <small class="text-dark" style="font-size:14px !important;">od {{$product->price}}&euro;</small>
                            @else
                            <small class="text-dark" style="font-size:14px !important;">{{$product->price}}&euro;</small>
                            @endif
                         </div>
                         @if($product->thumbnail)
                            <div class="col-3">
                            <span class="float-right">
                            <img src="{{$product->thumbnail->getUrl('showPreview')}}" style="width:80px;height:80px;border-radius:50%;object-fit:cover;" alt="">
                            </span>
                            </div>
                         @endif
                      </div>
                   </a>
                   @include('website.stores.product-modal')                                                          
                @endforeach
             </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

And my page is loading crazy slow. I know I'm something doing wrong and I know that there is a way to speed this up. How can I do that?